# Two menus in the same navbar?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to add a dropdown menu at the right side of my menu. When I declare a second menu with a new navwalker, nothing loads anymore and my site stays white (blank).

Here is my header

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="col-md-10">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="colum-lg-12 col-md-12 ">

            <?php bootstrap_nav(); ?>
          </div>


        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>
<!-- #masthead -->
</div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="site-content">
```

And here is my function.php

```
function bootstrap_nav()
        {
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'false',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a walker class unless you need to customize the second menu.

Follow the documentation here : [Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu_id'=>'your_menu_id'));
```

Add extra arguments as you need and place the menu directly to the right side div.